# How to avoid parameters wrapping single quotes around variable in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

We have BigQuery Dataset in below format:-

`class.division_A`

`class.division_B`

`class.division_C`

and trying to call these tables using parameter like division_A, division_B, division_C in string format but while calling these tables we are getting below error:-

`class.'division_A'` table not found. The single quote is being wrapped around automatically which we do not want.

Please suggest a solution to avoid this conflict.

Comment: Yes shashi , I am also facing same problem...if any one having any other solution to change table present in bigquery using filter to make interactive dashboard